# What word could I use to describe this?

Tags: word-choice

I'm trying to talk about how well two designs complement each other. My exact sentence is:

"I will use the focus of the designs as a measure of complementness."

However, "complementness" isn't a word (recognized by major dictionaries). What can I use instead to convey the same meaning?

Comment: How about **I will focus on the complementary design of the products.**?

Comment: The word you were looking for is [complementariness](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/complementariness). But it's unusual, and a bit of a mouthful, so you might want to consider rephrasing.

Comment: As JSanchez suggests, use complementary as a adjective, instead.

Comment: @JSanchez That's not what I'm trying to convey. Each design has a focus and I want to use that focus to compare the designs; *I won't* be focusing on anything.

Comment: So, the complementary parts of the products is the "focus of the designs."?

Comment: @dfg: You basic concept seems slightly "non-intuitive". If two things are *complementary*, that implies neither is complete without the other. In loose parlance this situation might arise by "happy accident", but when you're specifically talking about two things which were ***designed***, one would expect the "division into two halves of the original whole" to be fundamental to the design of each component. And the designers would always need to keep that "division" in mind, to make sure some vital part of the whole wasn't actually missed out by *both* projects assuming the other would do it.

Comment: I can't quite figure out how a "focus" could be a "measure" of something in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want "focuses of the designs"? They're different (complementary, so quite different), so they can't each have the same focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Synergy**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/synergy) might work in this case.

> I will use the focus of the designs to determine potential synergy.

The meaning is perhaps slightly different from your original statement of [**complementarity**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complementarity), but I think it might hit the nail on the head a bit better.

Synergy implies that the designs will work together and the combination will be better than each individual.

Otherwise, I would use complementarity.  It's not the most common word, but the meaning is "complementness" like you were looking for.